# How do I update value in DataFrame with mask when iterating through rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

With the below code I'm trying to update the column `df_test['placed']` to = 1 when the if statement is triggered and a prediction is placed. I haven't been able to get this to update correctly though, the code compiles but doesn't update to = 1 for the respective predictions placed.

```
df_test['placed'] = np.zeros(len(df_test))
for i in set(df_test['id']) :
    mask = df_test['id']==i
    predictions = lm.predict(X_test[mask])
    j = np.argmax(predictions)
    if predictions[j] > 0 :
        df_test['placed'][mask][j] = 1
        print(df_test['placed'][mask][j])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answering your question

*Edit: changed suggestion based on comments*

The assignment part of your code, `df_test['placed'][mask][j] = 1`, uses what is called [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). In short, your assignment only changes a *temporary copy* of the DataFrame that gets immediately thrown away, and never changes the original DataFrame.

To avoid this, the rule of thumb when doing assignment is: **use only one set of square braces** on a single DataFrame. For your problem, that should look like:

```
df_test.loc[mask.nonzero()[0][j], 'placed'] = 1
```

*(I know the `mask.nonzero()` uses two sets of square brackets; actually `nonzero()` returns a tuple, and the first element of that tuple is an ndarray. But the dataframe only uses one set, and that's the important part.)*

## Some other notes

There are a couple notes I have on using `pandas` (& `numpy`).

- Pandas & NumPy both have a feature called *broadcasting*. Basically, if you're assigning a single value to an entire array, you don't need to make an array of the same size first; you can just assign the single value, and pandas/NumPy automagically figures out for you how to apply it. So the first line of your code can be replaced with `df_test['placed'] = 0`, and it accomplishes the same thing.
- *Generally speaking* when working with pandas & numpy objects, **loops are bad**; usually you can find a way to use some combination of *broadcasting*, *element-wise operations* and *boolean indexing* to do what a loop would do. And because of the way those features are designed, it'll run a lot faster too. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the `lm.predict` method to say, but you might be able to avoid the whole `for`-loop entirely for this code.

Comment: Unfortunately the output still didn't work, while it updated some values to 1, it applied far more 1s then actually were intended in the code, I think I need to pass [j] through somewhere perhaps, but when I do I get: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: Yeah sounds right T-T Is `j` the row index of the DataFrame? if so, try `df_test.loc[j, 'placed']`. (The basic idea is, you should only be using **one set** of square brackets.)

Comment: I think I somehow need both, the mask groups the 'id' together through set() and then j returns the position within each set of the max() prediction. Is there a way to pass both through in the .loc[]?

Comment: Sure, I just edited into my answer what I *think* should work (IF I understand the `j` correctly).